# What size is the barrel connector required for a Sprint Airave 2.5 signal booster?

Tags: power-supply

Can someone please tell me what size barrel connector tip is needed for ac adapter for Sprint Airave 2.5 signal booster?

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely educated guess… But still a guess, so use this as a guide for your own research: Looking at the official documentation [here](http://www.sprint.com/landings/airave/files/Airave2.5_RTF_final.pdf) as well [as here](http://www.sprint.com/landings/airave/files/AIRAVE2.5_Eng_Online_TTG.pdf) it appears the device uses a fairly standard 12 Volt DC power supply. When I say “standard” I have dozens of them for hard drives, routers and even small printers. Electronic hobbyist site [SparkFun Electronics sells one for about $6.00](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9442) and [Other World Computing sells a similar one for $10.00](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MEP2BAYM15/). The amperage is what varies: Some operate at 1.5 Amps and I have seen some operate at 2 Amps.

As far as the actual barrel tip goes, I trust the [Other World Computing specs](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MEP2BAYM15/) which state: 3.0mm x 1.0mm female, center positive barrel. I trust that since I have a few of their devices that use that power supply and they are all pretty much interchangeable.